# The right word for obstructive bureaucracy

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word but I'm not sure it exists. Is there any word that resembles something like obstructive bureaucracy?

What I actually mean with this: Someone who blocks an extremely urgent request on the basis of bureaucracy.

An example:

- Harry, Chief of the Fire Department, didn't send out the fire trucks to the fire because the caller didn't fill in form A34.

What is this type of behaviour called?

Comment: Are you asking about a term to refer to the ***person who does this,*** or ***the act of doing this***?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I sharpened the question, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This isn't exactly the same but may help: [Idiom for someone who got a tiny fraction of power and abuses it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272480/idiom-for-someone-who-got-a-tiny-fraction-of-power-and-abuses-it). There are a couple of other questions that aren't quite the same, although it's not clear exactly what is being asked.

Comment: @SB Great: thanks. The person who does this is a [*jobsworth*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/534241/18696). Perhaps the "act" is "being a jobsworth", although a single word would be nice.

Comment: *Is there any word that resembles something like obstructive bureaucracy?*. I'd suggest the word *bureaucracy*. I cannot recall (aged BrE writing) nor immediately find, any use of the word with other than negative resonances.  And now I can look forward to others on this site digging those out!

Comment: Related: [kafkaesque](https://www.lexico.com/definition/kafkaesque). As far as I know, this can't be applied to individuals, though.

Comment: See also [Where did the word red-tapism come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/576222/where-did-the-word-red-tapism-come-from)

Comment: Also [blind compulsive adherence to the rules regardless of circumstance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/357979/blind-compulsive-adherence-to-the-rules-regardless-of-circumstance/358006#358006) [closed]

Comment: @DjinTonic In addition to your link, there are numerous duplicates on ELU found [by searching for redtape](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=red+tape)

Comment: Apologies for the closing snafus. I was able to reclose and chose as duplicate the one with the most answers applicable here. To the OP, this is a good question, but it happens to have been asked and answered many times so we redirect you there.

Comment: Closure was apparently justified but if the question were a true duplicate I would expect to find duplicate answers. However, on a quick look I did not find my own suggestion of Beadledom in existing answers. Unless I missed something, the closure has therefore denied the site of a small extra dimension to the original answers. This does not seem productive and the closure runs counter to the aim of extending knowledge. Anyone have any views on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only word I think of that fits your specification is **beadledom**:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/beadledom)
>
> beadledom:
> Noun
> fussiness and stupidity of minor officials; petty bureaucracy

> [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/beadledom)
>
> fussiness and stupidity of minor officials
> petty bureaucracy
> beadles collectively, and their characteristics as a class
> stupid or senseless officiousness

> Merriam Webster
>
> the characteristics felt to mark beadles as a class
> usually
> stupid officialism

The beadle is typically a low level bureaucrat:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beadle)
>
> beadle:
>
> an official who takes part in some church or university ceremonies
> in the past, an officer of the law who dealt with small offences in a local area

Such officials, lacking the reflective capacity of high lever officials, tend towards over-enthusiastic, pompous, self-important and unthinking application of rules and regulations.

Hence, one of the strongest associations of the beadle with this sort of behaviour was in Charles Dickens's *OliverTwist*. The refusal of food to a hungry child seems to qualify as denial of an urgent request rather well.

> [Fandom](https://oliver-twistcharles-dickens.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Bumble)
>
> Mr. Bumble, fictional character in the novel Oliver Twist (1837–39) by Charles Dickens. Mr. Bumble is the cruel, pompous and ignorant beadle of the workhouse where the orphaned Oliver is raised. **Bumbledom**, named after him, also characterizes the meddlesome self-importance of the petty bureaucrat.

Consequently, google's ngram shows the word to have been at its most popular in the latter half of the nineteenth century.

Anyone familiar with the adventures of Michael Bond's *Paddington Bear* (https://www.paddington.com/us/heritage/michael-bond/) will also find beadledom in the behaviour of the officious self-appointed custodian of street affairs *Mr Curry*:

[image]

Comment: The only problem with *beadledom* is that no one who has not read your erudite answer will understand what it means!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for the compliment. Isn't this the case with a number of answers on this site? We have to assume an educated, tolerant and reflective readership or we risk failing our questioners. Not easy.

Comment: Worth an upvote as it's absent from the duplicates.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am not persuaded that the answers in the original "duplicate", although many and well voted, are quite right for this question. However, it is nice to feel praised with faint damns.

Comment: @Anton While this is a good find, HP Hark's comment is a necessary comment, pointing out that an SWR answer here should not only provide the word but explain the conditions of its use, like how common it is, if it is local (AmE or BrE or nautical or medical or etc etc), register (formal informal), taboo, etc etc etc. Basically the things that a dictionary rarely supplies.

Comment: Wow nice, that's a sharp answer. I will wait accepting your answer as to see what else might come in.

Comment: 'I am not persuaded that the answers in the original "duplicate", although many and well voted, are quite right for this question.' No, they don't fulfil the 'block[ing] an extremely urgent request on the basis of bureaucracy' condition. But then neither does 'beadledom'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Asking for more food when almost starving might just be seen as urgent by most of us. That is one of the aspects of the beadle in Oliver Twist, is it not? I thought this to be well known but have added to the answer for completeness.

Comment: The etymological fallacy. There have been many beadles besides Bumble. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beadledom#:~:text=Definition%20of%20beadledom,a%20class%20usually%20%3A%20stupid%20officialism) has merely 'stupid officialism'. I haven't come across any mention of extreme urgency.